# Why Is My Font-Family Affecting a Wrapping Issue?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face

I've got a fixed-width `ul` with inline `li`s. Inside some of the `li`s i've got `a` with links. I'm essentially making tabs. I've set all the `li`s with fixed width's that up directly to the width of the `ul`. This works fine in Chrome. In Opera and Firefox it's a pixels off. But in IE, the `li`s wrap around onto a new row. I stripped my HTML and CSS down as much as possible and put it in a JSFiddle. I discovered that for some stinkin reason, `font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;` causes this to happen. When i remove it, it's fixed. I'd like to know WHY???

HTML:

```
 <ul id="menu">
                <li class="side"></li>
                <li class="spacer first"></li>
                <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                <li class="spacer last"></li>
                <li class="side last"></li>
            </ul>
```

CSS:

```
    body { font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
ul#menu {
       width:1110px; 
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
  }
ul#menu li.side
{
padding-right:100px;
      }
ul#menu li.spacer.first
{
    padding-right:85px;
}
ul#menu li.spacer.last
{
    padding-right:85px;
}
ul#menu li.side.last
{
    background-position:0px 0px;
    padding-right:100px;
}
ul#menu li.spacer
{
   padding-right:84px;
  }

ul#menu li a 
{ margin-right:-4px;
    text-align:center;
    width:122px;
    font-size:x-large;
      display:inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top:13.5px;
    padding-bottom:14.5px;
    background-color:blue;
    color: #000;


   }
```

You can see the behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/GfSLC/14/  Thanks! Let me know if i need to provide anymore info.

Comment: @Knu... what? "comment reminder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simply that browsers render pages slightly differently. A different font will affect the width and height of an element with `width:auto; height:auto`. For example the height of your `<a>` shrinks by 3px if you remove the `font-family`. Different font glyphs will consume different amounts of space.

In this case, the problem is that one browser has calculated the width of all the `<li>` to be greater than the width of the containing element and it is spilling over to the next line. To fix this you can either:

- apply the font-family to the `<li>` instead of `<body>`
- reduce the width of the spacer elements by 1-2px

Also, IE8 in quirks mode renders the page as expected; in standards mode it overspills the container.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose my problem was trying to use padding as a substitute for width - the font will add on to that, wheras with width the font doesn't affect it.